# How to preserve background colors between Multiple JFrames

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe

Within my program I have a method to change the frame colours. I also have a method to open a new `Jframe` which is used as a settings menu for the app. However the values set in the initial jframe will not carry over.

How may I preserve the colours set in the initial `Jframe` and have them load into the settings object as it is created ?

Comment: Put the colors in a model class, and pass an instance of the model class to your multiple JFrames.

Comment: Required reading: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your new `JFrame` with a `Color` parameter and set the background color after you called the default constructor.

```
public SecondJFrame(Color c)
{
    this();
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
}
```

Another way is to set the background color after you initialized your second `JFrame` in your initial `JFrame`:

```
SecondJFrame secondJFrame = new SecondJFrame();
secondJFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(this.getContentPane().getBackground());
secondJFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

user singlton design pattern add to it the Setting class you have as follow

```
public class SettingManager{
     private static YourSettingClass setting = null ; 
     private SettingManager(){}
     public static YouSettingClass getSetting(){
              if(setting==null){
                 setting = new YourSettingClass(); 
                 return setting; 
              }
         return setting ; 
     }
     // any utility method to change your setting will be here 

}
```

in each JFrame Constructor you can get the setting which is now global for the application

```
YourSettingClass setting = SettingManager.getSetting() ;
```

Comment: Dependency injection ís favorable over the Singleton pattern. It might not be an issue in this case, but Singletons often hide dependencies and it might be a problem to unitary testing.

Comment: Still you can use it by Single on YourSettingsClass that the case in spring framework in this case you dont need the manager and you will use the class directly by Autwire it